# How to run Mahout clustering in Local mode

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mahout, hadoop2, mahout-recommender

I want to run whole mahout clustering in Local Mode, Means my input will be local file system & output also Local file system.

***This is following steps which I follow to run mahout clustering in HDFS.***

mahout seq2sparse -i /mahout/seqinput/part-m-00000 -o /mahout/o_seqsparse -ow

mahout canopy -i /mahout/o_seqsparse/tfidf-vectors -o /mahout/o_canopy -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.SquaredEuclideanDistanceMeasure -ow -t1 50 -t2 25

mahout kmeans -i /mahout/o_seqsparse/tfidf-vectors -o /mahout/o_kmeans -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.SquaredEuclideanDistanceMeasure -c /mahout/o_canopy/clusters-0-final -cd 0.1 -ow -x 20 -cl -k 10

***Now I want this in Local mode like this.***

mahout seq2sparse -i <*Local_file_system_input_file_path*> -o <*Local_file_system_output_file_path*> -ow

mahout canopy -i <*tfidf-vectors_file path*> -o <*o_canopy_output_path*> -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.SquaredEuclideanDistanceMeasure -ow -t1 50 -t2 25

mahout kmeans -i <*tfidf-vectors_file path*> -o <*o_kmeans_output_path*> -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.SquaredEuclideanDistanceMeasure -c /mahout/o_canopy/clusters-0-final -cd 0.1 -ow -x 20 -cl -k 10

Please help me to resolve this. 
Thanks in Advance.